# Deploying Python Flask Web service in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda

I have written the below code and have deployed in AWS Lambda using deployment package :

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request
app = Flask(__name__)

books = [
{'id': 0,
 'title': 'A Fire Upon the Deep',
 'author': 'Vernor Vinge',
 'first_sentence': 'The coldsleep itself was dreamless.',
 'year_published': '1992'},
{'id': 1,
 'title': 'The Ones Who Walk Away From Omelas',
 'author': 'Ursula K. Le Guin',
 'first_sentence': 'With a clamor of bells that set the swallows soaring, the Festival of Summer came to the city Omelas, bright-towered by the sea.',
 'published': '1973'},
{'id': 2,
 'title': 'Dhalgren',
 'author': 'Samuel R. Delany',
 'first_sentence': 'to wound the autumnal city.',
 'published': '1975'}
]



@app.route("/listbooks",methods=['GET'])
def hello():
return jsonify(books)

@app.route("/getbookbyid",methods=['GET'])
def getBybookid(event,context):
if 'id' in request.args:
    id=int(request.args['id'])

results=[]

for book in books:
    if book['id']==id:
        results.append(book)
return  jsonify(results)
```

I have configured API Gateway to hit the lambda function for a GET request.
When i am trying to hit the endpoint using postman I am getting :

**Working outside of request context** error

Any pointers

Comment: Are you indenting your code properly? doubt it will fix your issue but I tried your code and its the first thing that I noticed, when I fixed it the program ran with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Working outside of request context" is a Flask error, not an API Gateway or Lambda error. It happens when your Flask app tries to access `request`, or anything that uses it, outside of a request context.

As @BSQL suggests, this seems to be because of the incorrect indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below line. It will solve your error.

```
app.app_context().push()
```

-Prasanna.K

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).